# Laravel migration - how to change the `id` field to be primary and auto-incrementing later

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-migrations

My table 'sales_order_details' has the `id` field  as integer 'int(10)' with a default value `0`. I need to change it to be a primary auto-increment  key in migration.

I tried in the following way :

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('sales_order_details', function (Blueprint $table){

         $table->integer('id')->default(NULL)->change();
         $table->increments('id')->change();

       });
    }

  public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('sales_order_details', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropPrimary('id')->change();

       });
    }
```

I get the following errors:

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table def
 inition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
 (SQL: ALTER TABLE sales_order_details CHANGE id id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREM
 ENT NOT NULL)

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table def
 inition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

[PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table def
 inition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

How to make the migration properly ? I am using version 5.4

Comment: Why you are writing these both lines $table->integer('id')->default(NULL)->change();         $table->increments('id')->change();
Only second one is required for increments.

Comment: Won't `default` and `increments` make problem if used together ?

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this

```
  public function up()
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE sales_order_details MODIFY id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT");            
    }

  public function down()
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE sales_order_details MODIFY id INT NOT NULL");
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE sales_order_details DROP PRIMARY KEY");
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE sales_order_details MODIFY id INT NULL");
    }
```

This is the one of the way you can achieve your goal, i hope this is helpful for you

Comment: How did you remove the default value from `id` ?

Comment: If primary key is there then you can not able to give null value so i have first drop primary key and then set column as nullable and in nullable filed we don't need to give default null value

Comment: I am talking about the `up` method. You did not remove the default value there.

Comment: As per SQL stander you can't able to add primary key as null and as per you up method you can take primary key field as null so i have remove this